# How to know which hyperlink is clicked Lightning

Tags: lightning

I have a lightning componenet "commonLightningComponent" with apex class "commonClass" associated with it.

I have two hyperlinks on a new lightning component "baseComponent". below is my component code:

```
<aura:attribute name="Url1" type="String" default="./commonClass?id=" description="URL to the common page." />
<aura:attribute name="Url2" type="String" default="./commonClass?id=" description="URL to the common page." />

<li class="slds-item"><a href="{!v.Url1}">commonpage1</a></li>
<li class="slds-item"><a href="{!v.Url2}">commonpage2</a></li>
```

When clicking the above 2 links, it redirects to the same commonLightningcomponent page.
Once, we are on the common page, I want to call different methods from the common page helper if the link clicked from url1 and url2.
I I was trying to find a way to capture which hyperlink is clicked from the base page that caused redirect to the commonpage.

Comment: I have a lightning component where I will redirect on the hyperlink click. For two hyperlinks, i'll redirect to same component. But I have to call different methods in apex if the link clicked is 1 or 2. So i'm trying to get the hyperlink which user clicks to call methods accordingly.

Comment: @sfdfox I updated the question.

Comment: do you have to stick on to native html (ie) a href (or) are you open to looking at ui:outputURL? if you are open to the later you can use  event.getSource().getLocalId(); based on the aura:id you assign for each ui;ouytputURL and redirect the user to custom url using force:navigateToURL

Comment: I tried event.getSource().getLocalId(); It is giving undefined error

Comment: Did you assign aura:id to the ui:outputurl component?